# Image not working in Head tag with gulp

Tags: gulp

When i setting png image as favion icon then its working fine in locally.
bt when i build with 'gulp build' then png image name is renamed bt in  remained same . so on that path png imane not found.

what is the solution of it .

Comment: Please show your gulpfile.js

Comment: here is my gulp file==>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brpatel8650/test/master/gulp.js